# FragmentTest app is not working, my app keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

My app crash when ever I try to run my program .This is the code I am using .

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void selectFrag(View view) {
     Fragment fr;

     if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
         fr = new FragmentTwo();

     }else {
         fr = new FragmentOne();
     }

     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //Inflate the layout for this fragment

  return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}
}
```

FragmentTwo.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //Inflate the layout for this fragment

  return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment No.1"
    android:onClick="selectFrag" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="selectFrag"
     android:text="Fragment No.2" /> 

 <fragment
    android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#00ffff">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="This is fragment No.1"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment_two.xml is also same as fragment_one.xml but in the TextView I am printing fragment no.2 instead of fragment no.1.

And in my AndroidManifest.xml file the min sdk version I am using is 11. Please guys enligthen me were I am going wrong and correct me .

I copied the code from  [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)

Comment: what's the error in the logcat?

Comment: `android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"` - is this the name of your package? **com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest**? If not, replace your package name in that line.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Malooga for helping me out. My package name is com.example.fragmentstest

Comment: So, your solution is to change the above line to: `android:name="com.example.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your package name is `package name is com.example.fragmentstest`, change this line:

```
android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
```

to

```
android:name="com.example.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
```

in `main_activity.xml`

Comment: Yup I have already done it and it is working fine. Thanks dude.. :)